# Multiple repositories not being searched for maven

Tags: maven, nexus

In my settings.xml I have configured this -

```
<mirrors>
     <mirror>
                        <id>lon33881xus</id>
                        <name>Project Nexus Repo</name>
                        <url>http://lonrs08358:9093/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                        <mirrorOf>central,maven2-repository.dev.java.net,thirdparty1</mirrorOf>
                </mirror>

        <mirror>
            <id>lon80813</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>                <url>http://lon3388x1us:1083/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                </mirror>
                 <mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://lonrs03296:1081/nexus/content/repositories/riskit_common_snapshot/</url>
        </mirror>
<!--<mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
                </mirror> -->
    </mirrors>
```

But still when the maven build runs only the 1st repository is seahced for jars and then the build fails as it is unable to find jars which are present in 2nd repository. I want jars to be searched in 1st repo and if not found then in 2nd. I am new to maven please help.

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is configure your local nexus to use `http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases`. Add this site to nexus as `proxy`.

Then your configuration should be like this:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://lonrs08358:9093/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

After that all actions are done behind the scene. When your local nexus does not have library it will download from proxy and then you should receive that library also in your local repo.